# Dynamic Renaming LaTeX output

Tags: xetex, pdftex, pdf, texmaker, output

Is it possible to code into the .tex file a method for specifying its name.

E.g. if I wanted it to be named based on the date, would it be possible to dynamically name as such:

filename_DATE_othervariable.tex, filename_DATE_othervariable.pdf

Compiler: XeLaTeX
Program: Texmaker

Comment: Well, obviously not the name of the very file the code is in ;). What do you mean exactly?

Comment: Note that your editor would likely get quite upset if a file disappears while open. At least, mine gets very worried if this happens or even if its contents gets changed by another programme. You cannot change `\jobname` once compilation has started. So output has to go to the output file set when `xelatex` is invoked. Normally based on the `.tex` but you can change this on the command line if you wish. Or using something like Arara, I think.

Comment: You could pass the name on the command line to the option `-jobname`. This means you could both pass it to `-jobname` and to a macro that you you also use *in* the `.tex` file.